# Is a server running iis with a certificate issued by godaddy vulnerable to heartbleed

Tags: iis, heartbleed

Is a server running IIS that is hosted by rackspace but using an SSL certificate issued by godaddy vulnerable to heartbleed?

Since it seemed that somebody thought this was worthy of down-voting, let me generalize the question a bit: if an IIS server is not otherwise at risk for heartbleed, is there a risk if it's certificate issuer was?  GoDaddy themselves recommend that "For additional security, we recommend that you rekey your SSL certificate." (http://godaddyblog.com/open-ssl-heartbleed-weve-patched-servers/)  So, what risk is there, if any, to the non-GoDaddy hosted IIS servers from GoDaddy being affected?

Answer (score 5):

No.   IIS doesn't use OpenSSL.

Comment: *As long as you're actually getting the SSL connection from the IIS server and not some other forward-facing server... like a reverse proxy. Not even sure RS offers that kind of config.

Answer (score 1):

If you want some reassurance, test your web site with the tools found in this answer:

[How to use the internet while Heartbleed is being fixed?](https://superuser.com/a/739440/314582)

The one from ssllabs https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/ does a very good job of listing all the servers behind a domain name. Try google.com for example.